# Parallelization (foreach) is not working in R

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I have a *foreach* loop in my code to reduce the run time. The problem I am facing is, I am not getting all the input records in the output. Below is the code snippet.

```
    # my_df has 100 records
    library(doMC)
    library(foreach)
    no_cores <- detectCores()
    registerDoMC(no_cores)
    # nrow(my_df)=100
    output <- foreach(combo = 1:nrow(my_df),.combine=rbind) %dopar% 
    {
     df <- my_df[combo,] #taking 1 row at a time

             ### do some operations ####
      score <- sum(another_df$score1+another_df$score2)

     if(score>score_cutoff){
     df$score <- score        
     }else{
     df$score <- 0}

     df; #rbinding *df* to *output*
    }
```

The output data frame should contain 100 records, but I am getting a random number of records (less than 100 every time). I have used *foreach* many times but this is the first time this is happening.

Can anybody help me with this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you're performing calculations on `my_df`? Can you elaborate a bit what your operations are?

Comment: @Val, I have edited the code in the question. All I am doing is calculating _SCORE_ and adding that value to _df_

Comment: @santhoshverma: Where do you declare `another_df`? Before the `foreach` statement? What is the general format of `another_df`? 2-column data.frame?

Comment: @ChiPak,
Yes `another_df` was created outside of `foreach` statement. It is in `data.table` format and it has more than 2 columns.What I am trying to understand here is, will there be any issue with `parallel processing` or `doMc` package if we refer to any data outside `foreach` statement?

Answer (score 0):

So for `foreach` you paralellize over your index `i`. In your case that would be the number of rows of your data `my_df`.

Every calculation you do will be then an element of the list `output` which you bind together using `rbind`. So far so good.

I cannot really say how exactly you arrived at your result, but generally I don't think it's a good idea to assign so many variables inside the `foreach` loop.

this is how I would solve it, and the result looks ok (has 100 rows):

```
library(doParallel)
no_cores <- detectCores()

cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)
registerDoParallel(cl) 

# simulate your data    
set.seed(42)
my_df <- data.frame(A=sample(1:1000,100),B=sample(1:1000,100))

cutoff <- 500

output <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(my_df),.combine=rbind) %dopar% 
{

  data.frame(A=my_df$A[i],B=my_df$B[i],Score=ifelse(my_df$A[i]+my_df$B[i] > cutoff,my_df$A[i]+my_df$B[i],0))

}

stopCluster(cl)
```